# проблемы с памятью VBO в режиме релиза

Tags: c++, opengl, память

Использую VBO, opengl, C++. В режиме Debug  никаких проблем нет, но при переключении на релиз приложение виснет. Методом тыка выяснил, что виснуть оно перестает, если снизить размеры выделяемой под буфер памяти до смешных значений. В debug все нормально с объемом буквально в 1000 раз больше. В чем проблема?
И еще, при переходе из полноэкранного режима в оконный и наоборот все рушится из-за переполнения значения приблизительно один раз из шести...

```
include <gl\gl.h>       
include <gl\glu.h>      
define GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB 0x8892
define GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB 0x88E4
define GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB   0x88E8
define GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB   0x88E0

struct vbo                          
{                           
    GLuint pointer;
    int n = 0;
    GLfloat ARRAY[840000];
} vbo[12];

typedef void (APIENTRY * PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC) (GLenum target, GLuint buffer);
typedef void (APIENTRY * PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC) (GLsizei n, const GLuint *buffers);
typedef void (APIENTRY * PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC) (GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
typedef void (APIENTRY * PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC) (GLenum target, int size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage);
PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC glGenBuffersARB = NULL;
PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC glBindBufferARB = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC glBufferDataARB = NULL;
PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC glDeleteBuffersARB = NULL;
int InitGL(GLvoid)
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(back, back, back, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_FOG);
    glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);
    glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);        
    glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.05f);          
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);      
glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 3500.0f);             
glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 8000.0f);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, LightAmbient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glGenBuffersARB = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB");
    glBindBufferARB = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBufferARB");
    glBufferDataARB = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferDataARB");
    glDeleteBuffersARB = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC)
    wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteBuffersARB");
    for (field = 0; field < 12, ...; glGenBuffersARB(1, &vbo[field].pointer), field++);
            BuildFont(); 
return true;
}
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{
for (field = 0; field <= 12; vbo[field].n = 0, field++);
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glFlush();
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[0].pointer);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[0].ARRAY), vbo[0].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vbo[0].n);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[1].pointer);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[1].ARRAY), vbo[1].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vbo[1].n);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[2].pointer);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[2].ARRAY), vbo[2].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vbo[2].n);
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glTranslatef(..., ..., ...);
        glRotatef(...1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(...0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[9].pointer);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[9].ARRAY), vbo[9].ARRAY, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
            glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vbo[9].n);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[10].pointer);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[10].ARRAY), vbo[10].ARRAY, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vbo[10].n);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[11].pointer);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            if (...)
                glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[11].ARRAY), vbo[11].ARRAY, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vbo[11].n);
            glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[7].pointer);
            glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
            glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[7].ARRAY), vbo[7].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vbo[7].n);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[8].pointer);
        glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[8].ARRAY), vbo[8].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vbo[8].n);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbo[6].pointer);
        glInterleavedArrays(GL_C3F_V3F, 0, NULL);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat) * sizeof(vbo[6].ARRAY), vbo[6].ARRAY, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vbo[6].n);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
return true;
}
```

Comment: покажите код. Причин может быть тысяча.

Comment: @Мстислав Павлов
Вот, приложил к вопросу код.

Comment: Я сейчас в отъезде, на следующей неделе приеду, посмотрю в чем беда

Comment: В каждом рендере вы пересылаете данные из ЦПУ памяти в ГПУ (glBufferDataARB). Это потому что ваши буфферы обновляются для каждого кадра? Это не быстрая операция. Насчёт отличия дебаг от релиз, то проблема может быть в коде. Не инициализированные переменные например.